# How do i properly configure multiple multiple SECURE virtual hosts - Apache 2.2.15 & RedHat 6

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, virtualhost, https

To start, this question might overlap with others but I almost feel like this is a Red Hat issue regarding the "how to properly configure it" part.

I have a few websites being served from the same IP address, no problems there. However, I want to give some of those websites a little protection through HTTPS. In RedHat, the ssl.conf file is referenced in the https.conf file and they seem to work well with each other.

Documentation had pointed me to creating a .conf file for every secure website I want and place that file in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ directory which also contains the ssl.conf file. Assuming all the directives are set up properly, would i need to reference the ssl.conf file in the secureWesite.conf file placed in that directory?

Second, there is an option of giving apache its own key pair but when it comes to each website having its own key pair how would that work? Im not interested in paying $500 per year for the wild card cert so are there any options out there? I hold mention that I only have one IP address at this time.

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: You can get a wildcard and/or multi-site certificate from [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com) for only about $60/year.

Comment: That is a more reasonable cost. Thank you for that resource!

Comment: Do you know of any that don't require your passport and drivers license to be scanned over?

Answer (score 1):

RedHat 6 supports using multiple individual certificates for multiple virtual hosts all on the same IP address.  The technical term for this is "[Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)" (SNI)  You may essentially just give each site its own certificate, defined via the `SSLCertificateFile` directive in each Virtual Host config.

Alternately, you could use a single UCC certificate with multiple Subject Alternative Names.  This cert would list all the sites you host as alternative names, and would be used for every site.  I would say SNI is the more 'official' way to do it, and makes it easier to move sites, revoke certificates, etc.  But using UCC/SANs is perfectly viable, and might even be cheaper.

As far as multiple config files go, as John mentioned, it's a good practice, but not required.  It makes comparing/modifying sites much easier than dealing with a single behemoth config.

Comment: Thank you for the tip here. So, I have tried to add a custom config for the ssl protected site and save that file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ directory location. This is, of course, the directory where the ssl.conf file is located. When i reboot httpd, the server doesn't start. Ok, so then i remove that file and place the same virtual host configuration in the httpd.conf file and restart. The same problem comes up. The server doesn't start. 

Is there something particular to RedHat going on here?

Comment: Do you get any output from apache indicating what the problem is?  Is Apache actually configured to start at system init?  Does your existing httpd.conf file have `Include conf.d/*.conf` or something similar, to pick up your subsite.conf file?

Comment: Apache is starting at boot and the config file picks up the Include Directory. The same thing happens if the config file is located in the conf.d/ directory or the httpd.conf file

Comment: So what error are you seeing?  Is the site simply not showing up with `apachectl -S`?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to reference the `ssl.conf` file once, in the main `http.conf` file. Dropping the one-config-file-per-vhost model into `conf.d` is more of a "common practice" than a requirement. The problem you will run in to is that you can only have a single site per IP with non-wildcard SSL certificates. You can use self-signed certificates, but those will have their own set of issues to deal with on the client side.

Comment: So, it sounds like the "common practice" will be picked up and read by apache with out issue. IN the mean time, i could use self signed certs for testing. Thank you for the tip